# X Server Doesn't Start Until After Decryption Of HDD on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: xserver

For some reason X Server isn't starting until I decrypt the drive. I have full disk encryption, and basically enter the decryption key on a black screen & then X Server starts and the graphics appear on the screen. How do I get X Server to start so I can see the decryption screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If the whole disk is encrypted, you can't use it until you decrypt it. You have to get the X server from disk to run it. You might be able to install an X server (and all that it needs) on a second, unencrypted disk, but then you might as well go with encrypted Home directories, instead.

Comment: So many people misunderstand FDE on Ubuntu. Here's a video proving you wrong

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4Bje0sLblo

Comment: How does that video "prove" anything?

Comment: How does it not?